# How do I stop reading a line when I encounter a whitespace?

Tags: c++, c, ifstream, readfile

I'm opening a file and reading it using getline(x,y) currently but I want to stop reading the line when I encounter a whitespace and then continue reading from there. 
Thanks

Comment: Of the various functions to read from an `fstream`, how did you decide on `std::getline`?  It sounds like a *line* is possibly not what you want to *get*.

Comment: The standard input operator `>>` stops at whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formatted input will stop at white space:

```
std::string str;
while( file >> str)
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
```

Maybe instead you are looking for `isspace( int ch)` method:

```
#include <cctype>

if ( isspace( string.at(i)))
    // ... stop
```

Answer (score 0):

So u may want to read from file every single char and test with `if` statement does it equal to `whitespace`, so take look at function `getc`.

Comment: I see c tag.@NeilKirk

Comment: Fair enough. It has C tag indeed!